# ASP.NET custom configuration section declaration breaks IIS Manager Configuration Editor

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration, iis-7.5

I have a simple .NET custom configuration component that allows me to specify a custom configuration group and section in my ASP.NET 2.0 (the web project targets .NET Framework  3.5) web application's `web.config` file:

In my `web.config` I have the following declarations:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup 
      name="SimpleConfigGroup"
      type="CustomSettingsLib.SimpleConfigGroup, CustomSettingsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a58d3af5d6768c9">
      <section 
        name="SimpleConfigSection"
        type="CustomSettingsLib.SimpleConfigSection, CustomSettingsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a58d3af5d6768c9"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <SimpleConfigGroup>
    <SimpleConfigSection MySetting="Hello World" />
  </SimpleConfigGroup>

</configuration>
```

There are a couple of classes that provide access to this custom configuration section that reside in a class library project called `CustomSettingsLib`:

SimpleConfigGroup.cs:

```
using System.Configuration;
namespace CustomSettingsLib
{
  public class SimpleConfigGroup : ConfigurationSectionGroup
  {
    [ConfigurationProperty("SimpleConfigSection")]
    public SimpleConfigSection SimpleConfigSection
    {
      get { return (SimpleConfigSection)this.Sections["SimpleConfigSection"]; }
    }
  }
}
```

SimpleConfigSection.cs:

```
using System.Configuration;
namespace CustomSettingsLib
{
  public class SimpleConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
  {
    [ConfigurationProperty("MySetting", IsRequired = false)]
    public string MySetting
    {
      get { return (string)this["MySetting"]; }
    }
  }
}
```

The code to read the `MySetting` value looks like (`Default.aspx.cs`):

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using CustomSettingsLib;

namespace WebApplication4
{
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
      SimpleConfigGroup group = 
              config.GetSectionGroup("SimpleConfigGroup") as SimpleConfigGroup;
      SimpleConfigSection section = group.SimpleConfigSection;
      Response.Write(section.MySetting);
    }
  }
}
```

This works great and my web application can read the `MySetting` value from my `web.config` file.

Because these settings will be used in many web applications on Windows 2008 R2+IIS7.5 I then created an [IIS Configuration Schema extension](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/241/configuration-extensibility/) to allow this setting to be edited in IIS Manager's Configuration Editor feature rather than having to hand edit the `web.config` file.

I added an IIS configuration schema extension file to:

`%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema`

```
<configSchema>
  <sectionSchema name="SimpleConfigGroup">
    <element name="SimpleConfigSection">
      <attribute name="MySetting" 
                 type="string" 
                 validationType="nonEmptyString" />
    </element>
  </sectionSchema>
</configSchema>
```

I then added the following section definition to IIS's `applicationHost.config` file in the `<configSections>` element:

```
<section name="SimpleConfigGroup" 
         overrideModeDefault="Allow" 
         allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

The problem I am having is that when I open IIS Manager's Configuration Editor for the site:

[image]

Then select `SimpleConfigGroup` from the section drop down list it reports the following vague error:

> "There was an error while performing
>   this operation."
>   Details:
>   Filename:
>   \?\e:\sites\site1\web.config
>   Error:

Here is a screen shot of this error:

[image]

If I remove the .NET `<sectionGroup>` declaration from the site's `web.config` file I can edit the custom setting just fine using IIS Manager's Configuration Editor. However my web application can't run because the `<sectionGroup>` config info is required for the custom config section and for .NET to be able to parse the `web.config` file.

I've tried adding the `<sectionGroup>` to the root `machine.config` (and even dropping the configuration assembly into the .NET 2.0 framework assemblies folder) but I get the same error. I also tried signing the configuration assembly thinking there may be a trust issue but that hasn't helped either.

What I find strange is that the usual .NET Framework `<configSections>` in `machine.config` don't upset the IIS Manager Configuration Manager, nor do the .NET 3.5 System.Web.Extensions `<sectionGroup>` definitions in an ASP.NET 2.0 site, e.g. for `system.web` yet my custom config sections do.

Why is this? Is it a bug in the IIS Manager Configuration Editor?

**Update:**

Based on Scott's suggestion I added the following to my `applicationHost.config` file (leaving the `sectionGroup/section` declaration in the `web.config` file:

```
<sectionGroup name="SimpleConfigGroup">
  <section name="SimpleConfigSection" 
           allowDefinition="Everywhere" 
           overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

This generates the following error which is understandable because it's already defined in the `web.config` file:

[image]

---

I tried removing the `sectionGroup/section` declaration from the `web.config` but keeping the above `sectionGroup` declaration in `applicationHost`. IIS Manager's Configuration editor no longer lists the `SimpleConfigGroup` section.

---

I then tried this in `applicationHost.config`:

```
<section 
    name="SimpleConfigGroup" 
    allowDefinition="Everywhere" 
    overrideModeDefault="Allow" 
    type="CustomSettingsLib.SimpleConfigGroup, CustomSettingsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a58d3af5d6768c9"/>
```

IIS Manager's Configuration Settings editor can now see the section again without error, but because there is no section declaration in `web.config` the ASP.NET app throws an *" Unrecognized configuration section"* exception.

---

I also tried this in `applicationHost.config`:

```
<sectionGroup 
   name="SimpleConfigGroup" 
   type="CustomSettingsLib.SimpleConfigGroup, CustomSettingsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a58d3af5d6768c9">
  <section 
    name="SimpleConfigSection" 
    overrideModeDefault="Allow" 
    allowDefinition="Everywhere"
    type="CustomSettingsLib.SimpleConfigSection, CustomSettingsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a58d3af5d6768c9"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

Again, no dice, ASP.NET throws an *" Unrecognized configuration section"* exception and IIS Manager's Configuration Editor no longer lists the `SimpleConfigGroup` section.

---

**Progress:**

I reverted to first base and re-instated the `web.config` config section declaration so that the ASP.NET application could read the custom config values. I deleted the customer schema file from the IIS schema folder and reverted `applicationHost.config`'s `configSections` section back to factory settings.

One of the things I found interesting is that IIS Manager's configuration editor exposes the `system.web` settings and whilst there is a schema file for this (`ASPNET_schema.xml`) the schema sections aren't actually referenced in the `applicationHost.config` file. This leads me to belief that these files or the `sectionSchema` names are being handled in a special way.

To this end I unlocked the `ASPNET_schema.xml` file and added my schema definition:

```
<sectionSchema name="SimpleConfigGroup">
  <element name="SimpleConfigSection">
    <attribute name="MySetting" 
                     type="string" 
                     validationType="nonEmptyString" />
  </element>
</sectionSchema>
```

This didn't work and `SimpleConfigGroup` wasn't visible in IIS Manager's Configuration Editor. But no errors were thrown and the ASP.NET app could still read it's custom config values.

I then tried following the conventions used in the `ASPNET_schema.xml` schema file and added this instead:

```
<sectionSchema name="SimpleConfigGroup/SimpleConfigSection">
  <attribute name="MySetting" 
             type="string" 
             validationType="nonEmptyString" />
</sectionSchema>
```

This actually worked!:

[image]

The ASP.NET application continues to function and can read the custom config section AND I can edit the custom config section `MySetting` value in IIS Manager's Configuration Editor.

I then rolled `ASPNET_schema.xml` back to factory settings and tried recreating the custom `SimpleConfigSchema.xml` file in IIS's schema folder using the same definition and this works as well.

This is also **without** adding a reference to the config section in `applicationHost.config`.

I'm coming to the conclusion that the guidance on extending the schema where both IIS Manager's config editor AND ASP.NET need to consume the same section is slightly bogus.

Comment: thanks for the detailed post. Small question, is there a way to programmatically add `<configSection>` to `applicationHost.config` without having to manually edit the file? I've tried `appcmd.exe set config ...` but I cant figure out the exact command

Comment: never mind, I just found the answer in your other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750213/edit-config-custom-section-in-iis . Another possibly useful script: http://troyparsons.com/blog/2012/10/managing-iis-configsections-via-script/

Answer (score 3):

Hey Kev.  This worked for me right away using your examples.  Here's where I placed everything:

Path:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\simpleconfig.xml
```

Content:

```
<configSchema>
  <sectionSchema name="SimpleConfigGroup">
    <element name="SimpleConfigSection">
      <attribute name="MySetting" 
                 type="string" 
                 validationType="nonEmptyString" />
    </element>
  </sectionSchema>
</configSchema>
```

Path:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config (in <configSections> element).
```

Content:

```
<section name="SimpleConfigGroup" 
         overrideModeDefault="Allow" 
         allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

Path:

```
Site's web.config
```

Content:

```
  <SimpleConfigGroup>
    <SimpleConfigSection MySetting="Hello World" />
  </SimpleConfigGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've been beating my brains out over this one :)

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for looking at this: I know, that was the easy bit and works just fine. But I when add `/configuration/configSections/sectionGroup` and `/configuration/configSections/sectionGroup/section` declarations to the `web.config` file so that .NET can parse my custom config XML this seems to break IIS Manager's Configuration Editor. I've re-jigged the question and added some more detail.

Comment: If I understand your description, I believe the issue is that the <configSection> should only be in applicationHost.config and not anywhere else.  Basically you need a) the schema in the schema folder, and b) the section declaration in applicationHost.config and then c) *only* the <SimpleConfigGroup> part in your site's web.config.

Comment: Hi Scott....solved! I think the MS guidance on defining schema extensions that are also meant to be consumed by ASP.NET are a bit inacurate. See my update.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got a working solution.  There isn't a chance that you have shared configuration enabled and that your applicationHost.config isn't from the %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config folder?  It almost seems like your settings applied to that file aren't taking.  You may need to do an iisreset after applying them too since they are picked up when the app pool is created.  Your solution uses the config in the site's web.config, which is a good working solution too.

Comment: No, shared config isn't enabled. In my original approach the schema settings *are* being picked up it's just that the IIS editor chokes. I think this problem is related to duplication of `<section>` or `<sectionGroup>` where the `name` attribute is like a unique key and that you can never have more than one in a fully resolved/merged configuration (i.e. way back from `machine.config` right through to the deepest possible child `web.config` including merging of settings from `applicationHost.config`).

Comment: Hence the `ASPNET_schema.xml` schema definitions using a path based notation in the `sectionSchema` name attribute which the configuration editor seems to treat in a special way (i.e. you don't need to explicitely declare the section in `applicationHost.config`) thus avoiding duplicate `<section name="...">` key clashes. Or something like that. I'll dip into the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` code with reflector when time permits to confirm this.

Comment: Hey Kev.  All of this worked for me first try using the components that you provided.  Schema held the schema, nothing was placed in .NET config files, apphost held the section declaration (not the site's web.config) and the site's web.config held the actual setting.  I had full conf manager support with that setup.  My guess is that you may have had artifacts left over from early test that threw off your testing. You have a working solution now, which is the key part. But if you start fresh, it should work with the config that I confirmed. I placed section declaration within the existing one.